# MYSQL turning INT field to BIGINT, without loss of data

Tags: mysql, int, type-conversion, bigint

I currently have a mysql table which is reaching the maxint mark with the autoincrement column.

Is it save to change the field type to Bigint without loss of data?

Or do I need to use a duplicate table with a bigint field, copy all data, and then remove the original and rename the copy to be sure I don't lose data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BIGINT can hold all INT values so type conversion is possible without any loss of data.

```
ALTER TABLE <tbl> CHANGE <col> <col> BIGINT;
```

Comment: Great. Do I need to manually set the autoincrement counter after conversion or does it continue where it left off?

Comment: I'd expect it to continue. It's a table-specific thing and not column-specific after all.

Comment: Hmmm... I'd better first experiment with that then... long live mysql fiddle...
Thanks for your answer. I'll accept in a few minutes.